# Haskell program won't work on my notepad++, how do i make this program so its interactive?

Tags: haskell, notepad++

This is what I have,

```
doubleMe :: int->int
doubleMe x = x + x
```

And when I run it on notepad++

```
ghc hw.hs
Process started >>>
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( hw.hs, hw.o )

hw.hs:1:1: The function main' is not defined in module `Main'
<<< Process finished.
================ READY ================
```

**how do i make this program so its interactive?**

Comment: Probably just a typo in your question, but the signature of `doubleMe` doesn't work this way. You probably mean `Int->Int`: types are always uppercase, when you write them lowercase the compiler treats them as ad-hoc–introduced type _variables_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, you're running the program with `ghc`. What you want to do is first run `ghci` and then use the `:load` command to load your file. Something like this:

```
Prelude> :load blarg.hs
```

You can also load the file when calling the command: `ghci blarg.hs`. This might work better with Notepad++ than using `:load` from the GHCi prompt.

GHCi is the command for running the Haskell REPL, which lets you interactively evaluate expressions.

I don't have Notepad++ handy to check, but I'm sure there is some way to tell it to run `ghci` in the background and load files into it instead of using `ghc` directly.

If there isn't, you can always just run `ghci` in its own terminal window. In this case, you can use the `:r` command to reload a file after you've loaded it for the first time. This will save you quite a bit of typing. (`:r` vs `:load blarg.hs`)